# How to prevent message »Pager won't be used for less than 500 lines.«

Tags: psql

I have `\pset pager_min_lines 500` in my `~/.psqlrc`. Now, each time I start `psql`, it shows the message »Pager won't be used for less than 500 lines.«. I don't need that message, I specificly asked for this behavior, I don't need `psql` to tell me. This get's even more annoying, when I run `psql` from scripts where this message spams the output. How can I get rid of that message without using `-X`/`--no-psqlrc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message comes from the execution of the `\pset` command, which you asked `psql` to execute upon start.

Change your `.psqlrc` file and tell `psql` to be quiet:

```
\set QUIET on
\pset pager_min_lines 500
\set QUIET off
```